# Apps playable directly in a Facebook newsfeed

Tags: facebook, feed, social-media

Today I stumbled upon a app that was playable directly in a Facebook newsfeed [Newsfeed SmartApps](https://www.facebook.com/NewsfeedSmartApps/?fref=ts).

How is this possible? Is there a new feature that I might have missed? If so, how do I build such an app myself?

Answer (score 1):

They used to have that described under the name “Feed Gaming” in the docs at one point, but I think that section has now been removed.

Basically all this is, is an SWF flash file, embedded via Open Graph meta tags as a “video” – details for that see here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video

Of course that won’t work on mobile devices that don’t have flash – but currently, it is the only way.

(Some FB partners can also embed HTML5 content as an iframe directly into newsfeed – but normal 3rd-party apps can not do that, as of now.)